# pushsharp push notification to iOS error with the certificate

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

Hi all I am new to iOS development, I have put in the deep end to get push notifications. I found pushsharp and was using this tutorial

[Tutorial I a using](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJcdyugkFZ0)

I have used a windows application instead of web application and add the latest pushsharp.  The code build and runs but i get the following exception

[image: Exception]

The error happens at the following location
[image: Error location in code]

I have revoked my certificate and recreated it several times and also i have tried exporting the certificate and the key. Both give me the same error.

When I am creating the certificate, I created one for iOS Development in Apple portal.

This is what I have tried so far
Based on comment from Jack Hua, i have tried the following

**Logged into apple portal and deleted**

- App ID's
- Certificates
- Provisioning profiles

*Xamarin visual studio has no provisioning profile as expected*

**Starting with a Clean slate**

1. Key Chain access
2. Request certificate from certification authority (Code Signing)
3. save the cert signing request
4. Registered a new app with bundle identifier and push services enabled
5. Add new provisioning profile
6. create certificate
7. Use the certificate signing request created (Step 3)
8. download certificate
9. Double click on the certificate to install into keychain 
   *(Keychain has new entry now)*
10. Right click an export a p12 
    *(If I do not do this I wasn't able to see the certificate in the provisioning profiles section)*
11. Select the certificate and create the provisioning profile
    *Re-open Xamarin studio and the provisioning profile is shown in the project properties*

**Now create the APNs develpment certificate**

12. Key Chain access
13. Request certificate from certification authority (APNs)
14. Save the cert signing request
15. Select the app id created (Step 4)
16. Edit App ID
17. Under push notification select create certificate
18. Select the certification signing request(Step 14)
19. Download the certificate
20. Double click on the certificate to install it
    *(Now two entries show in Keychain certificates, one for code signing and another for APNs)*
21. Select the APNs certificate in keychain access and export .p12 file
22. Include this in my sample project 
    *(Create as per the youtube video with appropriate device token)*

I still get the same Apns connection error.

What am i missing?

Based on Jack Hua comment I have further made this attempt.
I have set the validation flag to false, I still get the connection error however the inner exception is 'Invalid Device Token'

Made a bit of progress after some research, the device token i had has spaces removing the spaces i do not get any errors however the notification is never shown on my iPad. I am using Sandbox and iOS development certificates, provisioning profiles. Wondering is this a know issue in development and it will work in production. Any help is greatly appreciated guys!!!

Comment: Did you create APNS certificate? https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/generate-apns-certificate-for-ios-push-notifications-85e4a917d522 It's needed if you want to receive notifications

Comment: Yes I have I have used the following tutorial to create it, but obviously i created a development one (iOS Development) 

https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File

Answer (score 1):

That error message is generated when creating an ApnsConfiguration object, see [source code](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/PushSharp.Apple/ApnsConfiguration.cs#L113).

```
 if (!Regex.IsMatch (commonName, "Apple.*?Push Services")
                    && !commonName.Contains ("Website Push ID:"))
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("Your Certificate is not a valid certificate for connecting to Apple's APNS servers");
```

You are **not** creating a push certification... The tutorial you are following is creating a distribution provisioning profile that allows you to **submit your app to the Apple App Store** (not notification).

You can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#register-your-app-for-push-notifications) to generate a notification certification and config your app to enable the ability of push notofication.

Refer: [send-push-notification-to-ios-pushsharp-certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842024/send-push-notification-to-ios-pushsharp-certificate)

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for you comment. I have updated my question with what I have tried so far. I still have not luck, i get the same connection error. I started with a clean slate not sure what is that i am missing. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Abe Is the certification in your key chain prefixed with Apple Development iOS Push Services.? Is the .p12 path correct? Is the name of .p12 in the project same as your just created?

Comment: Is the certification in your key chain prefixed with Apple Development iOS Push Services.? 
Yes

Is the .p12 path correct? 
Yes (I get no path errors and the config is created)

Is the name of .p12 in the project same as your just created?
When i saved the p12 i saved it with different name. Does the name have to match, i though it only matters whats inside the file.

Comment: @Abe It seems no problem with your push certification.Can you try solution in this [thread](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/834)?

Comment: Hi Jack, I tried what you have suggested. I still get the Apns connection error however the inner exception is Invalid device token.  I have a simple app which is running on an ipad published from xamarin (Visual studio) which gets me the device token. I copy this device token in my windows forms application and try to send notification. Any thoughts?

Comment: Device token error is now resolved please see update to my question.